# Problems understanding nDCG format in pytrec_eval?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, information-retrieval

I am using `pytrec_eval` to calculate nDCG scores. For example, for `qrel`:

```
qrel = {
    'q1': {
        'd1': 0,
        'd2': 1,
        'd3': 0,
    }
}
```

And `run`:

```
run = {
    'q1': {
        'd1': 1.0,
        'd2': 0.0,
        'd3': 1.5,
    }
}
```

The nDCG score can be calculated like this:

```
import pytrec_eval
import json    
evaluator = pytrec_eval.RelevanceEvaluator(
    qrel, {'ndcg'})

print(json.dumps(evaluator.evaluate(run), indent=1))


 "q1": {
  "ndcg": 0.5
 }
```

My understanding is that nDCG takes into account the order of the retrieved documents indices, however, if you change the document ordering in the `run` you still get the same nDCG score, for example:

```
run2 = {
    'q1': {
        'd1': 1.0,
        'd3': 1.5,
        'd2': 0.0,

    }
}

evaluator = pytrec_eval.RelevanceEvaluator(qrel, {'ndcg'})
print(json.dumps(evaluator.evaluate(run2), indent=1))
```

Is this the expected behavior of calculating nDCG? What is the usage of the `qrel`? My undertanding is that the qrel tells you how relevant is the retrieved document, while run, is the resulting ranking of your query and IR system. Then, why if I change the order of `run` the nDCG score is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute the nDCG, you need to know what is the relevance of each document in a **ranked** list of results for this query. This information is contained in `qrels`. Ranking means that you first need to **sort** retrieved documents in descending order of their score. So you basically sort documents, and then go rank by rank, starting from the lowest rank (i.e. the top-scored document), which is 1. For each rank i you get the document's ground-truth relevance rel_i from `qrels`, and then you divide this relevance by log_2(i+1) to get a term for this rank i. You sum all these terms across all ranks, and you get the Discounted Cumulative Gain (DCG) for this query.

Therefore, `pytrec_eval` internally needs to create a sorted list from the dictionary mapping from doc ID to score, in order to get the ranks. This is why the order of the document-score pairs in the dictionary you pass as an input doesn't matter. Now, as an additional detail: to get the nDCG (i.e. normalized DCG), you divide the DCG by the Ideal DCG, which is the maximum DCG achievable by any model; to get the IDCG, you sort the *ground-truth* (as opposed to retrieved) documents in descending order of their relevance score and compute the DCG. Again, to get the ground-truth relevance scores you need `qrels`.